# JQuery Modal Form Input Field Autofocus Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, firefox, focus

I'm encountering an issue with a JQuery modal form with many labels and corresponding input fields in it.

The issue occurs when I open the JQuery modal form and scroll down. When I close and re-open the JQuery modal form, the form is auto-scrolled so that the first input field is at the top of the form and has keyboard focus. However, this cuts off the label and header above the first input field.

I have tried $("input").blur(), and that successfully disables keyboard focus on the first input element, but the modal form still automatically scrolls so that the first input form is flush against the top of the screen.

I have also tried placing a hidden input field above everything else in the JQuery modal form, but Firefox is smart about it and still scrolls to the first active non-hidden input element.

Has anyone encountered this situation before, and if so, does anyone know the proper resolution for it?

Comment: Just pondering... would it be a problem to reload the contents of the modal on open? That should kill the problem, albeit at the cost of a server request.

Comment: When you said "when I open the JQuery modal form and scroll down", I wonder why that is focussing on the first control? You don't have some javascript doing a `focus()` or `scrollIntoView()` anywhere do you?

Comment: Negative, I am not calling any focus() or scrollIntoView() functions in my code at all. I think it's JQuery-related, but I'm not sure. I could reload the contents of the modal, but I'm working inside a framework with significant delay (5-10 seconds, horrible) involved in server requests, so I've restricted myself to one server request on page load. I have resolved the issue (see below), although I'm frustrated that this seems to be a framework or JQuery quirk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. I used the scrollTop() method on the JQuery modal dialog div itself, like so:

$("dialog").scrollTop(0);

This is separate and distinct from autofocus/blur issues, as Firefox's autopositioning apparently does not tie with its autofocus.